# How to detect outlier detection in two dimensional arrays?

Tags: statistics

Given an array like:

```
[ 
  { final_amount: 20.0, shipping_amount: 5 },
  { final_amount: 30.0, shipping_amount: 5.5 },
  { final_amount: 25.0, shipping_amount: 105.5 },
  { final_amount: 325.0, shipping_amount: 125.5 }
]
```

How could I detect that

```
  { final_amount: 25.0, shipping_amount: 105.5 }
```

is an outlier?

Bigger final_amount means bigger shipping_amount, however we have some bad entries in our data set.

If I take into consideration only shipping_amount (with median and standard deviation) it removes some valid entries because it's not taking the final_amount into consideration.

Comment: Thanks Robert, didn't know about stats.sx.com. If you add it as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to go about any problem like this is to have a model of "normal" data and one or more models of "abnormal" data. Each of these is a p(data|category) for some category. Apply Bayes' rule to compute p(category|data) and make some choice among the categories, e.g. pick category with largest p(category|data). This a pretty wide-open field so good luck and have fun. Also you might get more interest on stats.stackexchange.com.